# Отслеживание выполнения функций JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firebug

Всем, привет! Уважаемое сообщество, подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом в браузере можно отследить какая именно функция JavaScript сработала в данный момент, например: на сайте есть несколько слайдеров и они по очереди листают картинки, по сути выполняется какая-то функция которая изменяет стиль css конкретного элемента страницы, а вот как узнать, что в данный момент сработала такая-то функция.

В firebag`е я вижу, что при перелистывании картинки влево или вправо происходит попиксельное увеличения значения свойства например **left** или **right**. Так как узнать, какая функция это выполняет?

Надеюсь смог изложить суть своего вопроса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно изучить работу breakpoints (т.н. [точек останова](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0)). Firebug умеет прерывать функцию при изменении атрибутов у DOM-узла, CSS-правил и [многого другого](http://getfirebug.com/doc/breakpoints/demo.html). Посмотрите [обучающие видео](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=how+to+use+firebug+breakpoints&oq=how+to+use+firebug+breakpoints&gs_l=youtube.3...6817.9657.0.9762.15.13.2.0.0.2.127.1049.11j2.13.0...0.0...1ac.1.nfvyw6cSWYw).

Answer (score 2):

Ну если функциями это делается, то в функции нужные вставить что-нибудь вроде `console.log("hello world")`, ну ессно со своим текстом :)

Comment: а так, еще можно попробовать это через events делать и уже через евенты выводить в `console.log`...

Comment: А что делать, если нет доступа к изменению кода?

Comment: тогда ваш ответ подходит, ТС не уточнил где что)

еще, теоретически, можно это userscripts обрабатывать... но это уже другая история...

Comment: Роман правильно подметил, я же именно и хотел чтобы не искать по всему, так то понятно, что можно и алерт вывести, зачем консоль напрягать, я вот и ищу где мне его вклепать, ну это я образно

Answer (score -2):

Да делайте `alert`'ы по ходу скрипта, найдете свою функцию.